# NoReverseMatch on context Data

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to access my context data but for some reason I get an error.

> Reverse for 'applicant_register3' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}'
>   not found

.....................................

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container paddingtop80 marginbottom30">
  <div class="jumbotron greenback">
      Test
      <a href="{% url 'registration:applicant_register3' pk1=project.id %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>   Add Applicants</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to use pk1 = project.id

My views should allow me to access it ..

```
class RecruitmentPage(generic.ListView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = "recruitment_index.html"
    model = Project 

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Project, id=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(RecruitmentPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         return context
```

I guessed that by providing the model in the generic view I could access it but it seems that I cannot ..

Can someone give me a hand ? 
thx

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: sorry .. I got Reverse for 'applicant_register3' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}' not found so apparently pk1=project.id is not found .. it is empty ..

Comment: It's not clear what your view is for. A list view is for displaying a list of objects. Your model is `Project` so you can loop through `project_list` in your template. The list view does not use `get_object`, so that method is not being called. You get the error because `project` does not exist in the template context.

Comment: My view will be to list project on that page .. but I need to add a button to add user to that project. My question is why it does not exist in my template context since Iinked my view to the model Project. How can I add it to my template ?

Comment: As I said, you have a list view, so you have access to *all projects* with `project_list` in the template. You loop through all projects with `{% for project in project_list %}`. You haven't shown any code that adds `project` to the template context. If you want to display a single project, then it doesn't make sense to use list view - `DetailView` would be better.

Comment: ok I got it, I clearly did not get the project_list in the list_view .. it is cleaer now thx.. I added the current_project in my context .. It worked. Ass it as an anwser that I can give the credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the `NoRevereseMatch` error because `project` is not in the template context.

A list view will not automatically call your `get_object` method. You could call it manually in your `get_context_data` method:

```
class RecruitmentPage(generic.ListView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = "recruitment_index.html"
    model = Project 

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Project, id=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(RecruitmentPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['current_project'] = self.get_object()
         return context
```

Now, in your template you can loop through the list of all projects with `project_list`.

```
{% for project in project_list %}

{% endfor %}
```

And you can access the project from `get_object` with `current_project`

```
{% url 'registration:applicant_register3' pk1=current_project.id %}
```